# Tests for significant difference between prediction errors of machine learning regression models

Tags: machine-learning, hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance

Are there any recommended statistical tests for significant differences between cross-validation (CV) estimates of prediction error of machine learning regression models?

I have 5 different random forest regression models that use different predictor sets. For each of those 5 predictor set ups 8 different target variables (numeric) were modeled. For model evaluation I applied a 5x10 CV and computed the normalized root-mean-square error (NRMSE) and R² of all 5 models. Now I would like to test the models for significant differences and verify that there are no significant differences between the model errors.

I want to test for significant differences of the NRMSEs of CV prediction errors in different settings between the 5 predictor set ups (5 groups):

1. of each target separately: 5 single values (each is the mean of
   50 CV NRMSE estimates) are tested against each other
2. of each target separately: the sets of 50 CV NRMSEs of the 5 models
   against each other
3. of all targets together: all 8 target mean CV NRMSEs are in one group and the 5 groups are tested
       against each other
4. of all targets together: all 400 target CV NRMSEs of the 5
       groups

I consider the following statistical tests:

- Kruskal-Wallis test
- ANOVA
- Tukey's range test (Tukey's HSD)

I excluded Wilcoxon signed rank tests and Student's t-test to avoid the multiplicity effect, because I have multiple groups to compare.

Which statistical tests would you recommend (also those that I didn't list)?