# How to test for significance of differences between metrics for two models? (Machine learning model selection)

Tags: machine-learning, statistical-significance, model-selection, scikit-learn, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

**Problem** - I want to test whether the difference in a metric (say AUC) between two models is significant. I have one vector of binary class predictions from a custom function and one from sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.

**What I tried** - So far, the closest thing I could find is the 2-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS-)test. I am not sure whether I should just test for differences between the prediction vectors, or between each prediction vector and true class vector. It does not make sense to me to do so, as I suspect that would rather tell me whether the estimator is biased.

**Related questions** -
I also found out that a KS-test is valid on a discrete distribution (see this paper by John Walsh, 1963: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02865912). Similar questions have been asked, but not answered here:

- [Tests for significant difference between prediction errors of machine learning regression models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445235/tests-for-significant-difference-between-prediction-errors-of-machine-learning-r)
- [Testing for statistical significance of the true positive detection rate between different machine learning models](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/559570/testing-for-statistical-significance-of-the-true-positive-detection-rate-between)

Comment: What's wrong with the answer to the last linked question?

Comment: @ChristianHennig Thank you for your comment! Maybe just that I don't get it. It suggests using the prediction vectors as x_i for a logistic regression and checking the p-value for each predictors factor, right? Will that not tell me the significance of the estimator itself, rather than a difference between the estimators?

Comment: The outcome would be a classification success/failure binary vector (this can be seen as some kind of information reduction but may be appropriate in some situations). The predictor would be binary here (because you have only two methods), with the two values corresponding to the two methods. If that predictor turns out to be significant, choice of method makes a significant difference. The important thing is to do this in a repeated measures/mixed effects kind of way to appropriately take into account the dependence structure in the data.

Comment: That helps a lot, thank you so much! Do you know if there's another, maybe more common way to achieve something similar? I am writing my thesis and it feels like I'm missing the elephant in the research community.

Comment: I don't see any elephant, neither apparently the people who read and didn't respond to the other two questions.

Comment: The Diebold-Mariano test could be useful maybe

Comment: @picky_porpoise thanks, I had a look and it seemed promising, but Diebold warns against using the test for model comparisons: https://www.nber.org/system/files/working_papers/w18391/w18391.pdf